# Determining whether a given language is regular

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, pumping-lemma

---

Suppose language $L = \{\,a^{i} b^{k} : k \text{ divides } i\,\}$.

Some strings in $L$ include …

- $\,a^{0} b^{1} = b \in L\,$ since $1 \text{ divides } 0$
- $\,a^{1} b^{1} = ab \in L\,$ since $1 \text{ divides } 1$
- $\,a^{2} b^{1} = aab \in L\,$ since $1 \text{ divides } 2$
- $\,a^{0} b^{2} = bb \in L\,$ since $2 \text{ divides } 0$
- $\,a^{2} b^{2} = aabb \in L\,$ since $2 \text{ divides } 2$
- $\,a^{4} b^{2} = aaaabb \in L\,$ since $2 \text{ divides } 4$
- $\,a^{0} b^{3} = bbb \in L\,$ since $3 \text{ divides } 0$
- $\,a^{3} b^{3} = aaabbb \in L\,$ since $3 \text{ divides } 3$
- $\,a^{6} b^{3} = aaaaaabbb \in L\,$ since $3 \text{ divides } 6$
- $\,\,\,\,\ldots\,\text{plus infinitely many additional strings that are members of }L\,\ldots\,\,\,$

---

Is $L$ a **regular** language?

---

Comment: Intuitively, when switching from reading as to reading bs, you need to have enough information in memory to determine if the number of bs is acceptable. This requires storing the number of as, which is beyond the capacity of any bounded amount of memory.

Answer (score -1):

Let $K = \{b^k : k \gt 0\} = \{b,bb,bbb,bbbb,\ldots\}$.  One may establish that $K$ is regular by (for example) constructing a deterministic finite accepter $M$ such that $K = L(M)$, the language accepted by $M$.

If $L$ were regular, then (by the closure of the family of regular languages under complementation and intersection) $L - K = L \cap \overline{K}$ would also be regular.

Next, apply the [**Pumping Lemma for Regular Languages**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) to the infinite regular language $L - K$ and derive a contradiction.  To derive a contradiction, one may consider $a^{\,p} \, b^{\,p}$ where $p$ is as described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).

Once a contradiction is reached, one may conclude that $L$ cannot be regular.